# Logic & Computability Problem

Tags: logic, computability, turing-machines

i read this sentence in one exam that be false. anyone could say why?

if predicate H(x) become false when a program with code r(x) halt on input l(x), then H be a computable predicate.

Comment: Is l(x) computable?  Does when mean $\Leftarrow$, $\Rightarrow$, or $\iff$ ?

Comment: Dear @DanielV not give in my textbook

Comment: I'm guessing that the answer is that R(x) might not halt when H(x) is true.

Comment: you means if we want to H be a computable predicate  R(x) might not halt when H(x) is true?

Comment: It might help if you also post the original question in it's original language, someone might be able to edit the question for you.  I know some people always want everything in English, but I think it is ok to add the original language to your post for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing at the interpretation to this question.

> if predicate H(x) become false when a program with code r(x) halt on input l(x), then H be a computable predicate

Suppose the range of $l(x)$ is all programs.

Suppose $r(x)$ is a simulator.

Suppose $H(x)$ is the predicate "$l(x)$ runs forever without stopping."

When $r$ stops the simulation of $l$ , you know that $H$ is false.  However, $H$ is the halting problem which is considered to be undecidable.  So $l$, $H$, $r$ are a counterexample.